# Where is a string stored without OS?

Tags: c, string, operating-system, undefined-behavior

The title is a bit wrong, but that's the best I can do with the English I know at the moment.

What I mean is:

I am currently creating my "toy" OS.

I am able to create a string like this in C:

```
int main() {
  char* s = "blah";
}
```

That means I am creating a pointer to a memory chunk, right?

I would think that, without an operating system, I would have to do the following:

```
int main() {
  char* s = 0x/*A random address here*/;
  s[0] = 'b';
  s[1] = 'l';
  s[2] = 'a';
  s[3] = 'h';
  s[4] = 0;
```

I haven't really tried the second, but I feel like both of these methods are undefined behavior, because I haven't registered the length of the string somewhere.

Can someone help me with this?

1. Where is the first `"blah"` stored in RAM since I haven't specified an address?
2. Is the second the correct way, if not, what is the correct way?
3. Is any of the methods I mentioned undefined behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are actually first storing it in your executable. And whatever platform you have, it is bound to have some sort of RAM. The toolchain will take care of moving your local variables there.

Comment: Oh and that second approach looks like a Segmentation fault or something similar waiting to happen. Don't do that unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: You can analyse the memory address of a variable stored using debugger(gdb).

Comment: Because you are asking, the answer is, "it doesn't matter to you"... The compiler, linker and OS are sophisticated bits of software that look after you and themselves... Until you are far more advanced, all you need to know is that the char array lives somewhere and is available to your code through the token 's'... "It is not wise to tip the vessel of knowledge. Patience and certain steps lead to progress.."

Comment: For `char* s = "blah";` the compiler allocates an unnamed array of `char` with static storage duration and initializes `s` to point to the first element of that array. The storage for the unnamed array could overlap the storage for other string literals. Attempts to modify the contents of that array lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I don't have an OS since I am developing a toy OS..

Comment: @IanAbbott Then if i were to do ```s[0] = 'B'``` to make the first character uppercase would be undefined behavior?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium From your first comment i understand it's like ```db "blah"``` in an assembly program, and then make a pointer with it's address?

Comment: Yes, but modification doesn't require a change in value, so `s[0] = 'b';` (no change in value) also results in UB.

Comment: More like `db "blah",0`, but it depends on the assembly language syntax.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand now. Thank you all for your help and your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally a compiler produces an output file that contains the code and data it generated and information about how they should be laid out in memory. A linker reads one or more of these files and produces a similar output file. When the program is executed, a program loader reads the executable file produced by the linker and puts the code and data in memory at appropriate places.

Some linkers also have options to produce a “raw” binary file that could be loaded into memory directly, if it has been appropriately prepared.

To make an operating system, you must have some way of loading your operating system. That could be a raw binary file that the hardware loads into memory, or it could be some file format that the firmware knows how to load. Modern general-purpose computers contain hardware and firmware that perform extensive operations to support loading the operating system. To create an operating system for such a computer, you will need to learn about the file format that its firmware uses.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning ROM, EPROM, etc. which--unlike most storage media--behave like memory which is (from the standpoint of the system where it is installed) magically contains whatever content is required, without the system having to do anything to load its contents.